# In C#, can Clipboard.GetData be forced to output quotes around every CSV value?

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

In C#, I'm using the following code to copy data from a WPF `DataGrid` to the clipboard, and then from the clipboard to CSV:

```
var originalSelectionMode = dataGrid.SelectionMode;
dataGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridSelectionMode.Extended;
dataGrid.SelectAllCells();
dataGrid.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dataGrid);
dataGrid.UnselectAllCells();

// this is the line that's not working quite right:
var text = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);

Clipboard.Clear();
dataGrid.SelectionMode = originalSelectionMode;

File.WriteAllText(fullPathToFile, text);
```

This code works in most cases, but there's a problem when you have multi-line text in one of the cells.  Let's say you have data in a grid like this:

```
A     |B     |C
-------------------
A1    |B1    |C1a,C2b
-------------------
A2    |B2    |C2a
      |      |C2b
-------------------
```

The `Clipboard.GetData` function only seems to insert double-quotes around the cell contents in the case where you have a comma or a double-quote character in your cell contents, but doesn't do it automatically if you have a line break in there, so the output with the above grid would look like this:

```
A,B,C
A1,B1,"C1a,C1b"
A2,B2,C2a
C2b
```

Note that it does put quotes around cell C1 but not cell C2.

Is there a way I can force `Clipboard.GetData` to always put quotes around every cell?  If not, how can I fix this?

Comment: No, but there's nothing to stop you from doing that after you get the data out. Also, those quotes would have been added by whatever .NET code put the data in there... it's not something that is built into the `Clipboard` class.

Comment: @Sheridan - adding the missing quotes is not a trivial problem.

Comment: @Sheridan, the quotes are put in the CSV by the [DataGridClipboardHelper.FormatPlainCell](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/PresentationFramework/R/68eaf75082b68e8f.html) method. It is true that it is not part of the *Clipboard* class, but it is part of the WPF DataGrid implementation (and its helper classes).

Comment: There is no direct way to configure a WPF datagrid to cater for multi-line CSV data. You could override its *OnExecutedCopy* method and implement the CSV generation code there, but that is not be done in a few code lines, and it would require you to create a subclass of DataGrid and use that subclass instead of the standard DataGrid in your UI...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use data binding and write the string to csv. I have created a sample class which can be binded to DataGrid and allow creation/editing of new rows( you can added notification on this class if reqd) :

```
 public class Data
{
    public Data()
    {
    }

    public Data(string col1, string col2, string col3)
    {
        Col1 = col1;
        Col2 = col2;
        Col3 = col3;
    }

    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
    public string Col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Now I override the Copy command of the datagrid to control custom copying:

```
 this.DataGrid.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Copy,
            new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(CopyClicked)));
```

In the CopyClicked, we create the data using the Data ViewModel binding class:

```
 private void CopyClicked(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        IList l = this.DataGrid.SelectedItems;
        foreach (Data data in l)
        {
            stringBuilder.Append("\"" + data.Col1 +"\",");
            stringBuilder.Append("\"" + data.Col2 + "\",");
            stringBuilder.Append("\"" + data.Col3 + "\"");
            stringBuilder.AppendLine();
        }
        //Write to a file or straight to clipboard etc
        Debug.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Ultimately I did write my own "to CSV" implementation that included some extra features for keeping Excel from behaving in "helpful" ways by turning, e.g. "01-01" into "Jan-01".